# After pod install Public folder is empty

Tags: cocoapods

i have with a project who uses cocoaPod, each time i try to install the pods. I have got this error

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/XXXXX/dev/Qridit/Pods/Headers/Public'

https://www.evernote.com/l/AGCa1mI0c51EZLSojPKyZPlMCKRShsT_sLI

Any help will be appreciate

bolo